# GoJS with Angular 8 Diagram and Palette in Separate Components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gojs

I have a very basic question about the best way to implement GoJS with Angular 8 where the diagram and palette are represented by separate components. This seems to me to be a more organized way to implement the GoJS library, however I'm uncertain if this would be feesible and what the best way to share data between the diagram and palette components would be.

Comment: There is a sample repo for providing a basic example of using GoJS in an Angular app.: https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/gojs-angular-basic

Comment: That example doesn't include a palette. I'm specifically looking for the best way to implement the diagram and palette being their own components.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on exactly what you want to do, but for a general case of needing a Palette with some Nodes you can drag onto a Diagram, you just need to define a Palette Component, that contains a div in which you initialize your Palette (probably in ngAfterViewInit), and a Diagram Component, that contains a div in which you initialize your Diagram (also probably in ngAfterViewInit).

If you need to bind data, such as node data, to these components, just pass them as @Input() properties from your wrapper Component.

We plan to release some Angular / GoJS Components to make this process even easier, but I cannot say when they'll be ready. Let me know if you have further questions.